# Laravel: Recursivly map object(s) and their children to named arrays

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, laravel-5.3

I want to use a web service; however, it requires data to be sent a certain way and I don't want to model my Laravel classes based on the web service.

What would be the best way to make a recursive mapping function that allows me to map the current object and all of its children (relations)?

For example, lets say I have a profile and it can have many users and these users can have many addresses.  ***Note: Example is in JSON, but I want to accomplish everything in PHP.***

```
// Starting Object - This object is equal to $profile below
{
  id: 1,
  swift_locator: 74,
  users: 
  [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Random",
    addresses: 
    [{
      id: 1,
      city: "Here",
      state: "somewhere"
    }]
  })
}

// PHP
$profile::convertForWebService();  // I need help figuring out what goes on in here

// Final Object
{
  profileId: 1,
  SWIFTLocator: 74,
  parties: 
  [{
    partyId: 1,
    partyName: "Random",
    addresses: 
    [{
      addressId: 1,
      city: "Here",
      state: "somewhere"
    }]
  })
}
```

How can I make a function that calls the same function on all of its children if they also have that function?

So *$profile::convertForWebService()* sees that each name in the collection has a *$name::convertForWebService()* method and executes it and *$name::convertForWebService()* sees that each address in the collection has an *$address::convertForWebService()* function and executes it so that I can end up with Final Object above.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of option available, you can simply use `array_map()` of PHP to do that or you can use package like http://fractal.thephpleague.com/